# enforce the type of an upper bounded wildcard?

Tags: java, generics

I have a variable that has several upper bounded wildcards, like so:

```
private Map< Class< ? extends MyClass1 >, List< ? extends MyClass2< ? extends MyClass3, ? extends  MyClass1> > > _variableName;
```

Is there any way to enforce that the bound value `? extends MyClass1` be the same for the Type of the Class class and the 2nd param of the MyClass2 class?

Comment: I do not know what you are trying to do. But it is too complex for sure.

Comment: @Vash - Reminds me of my favorite quote ever from StackOverflow: "_if it's not simple, it's not right._"

Comment: @jahroy, The answer is simple to assure that type safety. You just need to create a method with generic parameter that will create such Map. But having this type of construction, shows that the design is poor and will soon collapse.

Comment: I'd remove the wildcard on the List - IIRC you won't be able to map.get(aClass).add() otherwise. And the fact you repeat the upper bound smells - if MyClass2 is just a container like Map.Entry, then you may wish to have 2 separate Maps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes:

```
    public class Foo<T extends MyClass1> {
        private Map< Class<T>, List<? extends MyClass2<? extends MyClass3, T>>> bar;
        ...
    }
```

You could also do this with a generic method.  It depends on where you want to make the guarantee (and by extension, where the Map is instantiated), when defining the class or when calling a method that instantiates this Map.

UPDATE:

In response to the (correct) observation that this map will only contain one element, perhaps the questioner had this in mind instead:

```
    public class Foo {
        private Map<Class<? extends MyClass1>, List<? extends MyClass2<? extends MyClass3, ? extends MyClass1>>> bar;

        public <T extends MyClass1> void add(Class<T> myClass, List<? extends MyClass2<? extends MyClass3, T>>> myList) {
            bar.put(myClass, myList);
        }

        ...
    }
```

Assuming this is the only way to add elements to your private map, then that ensures the types always match.

Comment: Won't this allow only one element in the Map? Because IIRC, a Class<S extends T> is not a Class<T>.

Comment: @ignis Or two elements if the map supports a null key :)